# Using slice tool on an entire artboard

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, cmyk, artboard, slices

I'm trying to make a 4 panel graphic presentation for one of those [table-top convention displays](http://www.exhibitors-handbook.com/Includes/DownloadFile.aspx?name=GraphicTemplates/pdf/folding-display-panels/hero/Hero_H08_template.pdf) so I made a new file with the right resolutions, bleeds etc set.

I also made it 4 artboards in 4 columns like seen in the image below with the proper spacing etc.

[image]

My question is, how do I save each artboard as individual files? When I try the slice tool I can't seem to just select a whole artboard and save all of it, do I have to flatten the layers or something? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is a way to automate it, I haven't needed to research that myself, but you can save each one individually in the Save As menu:

[image: artboards]

Comment: Oh now that is one damn handy tidbit of info, thank ya sir, cheers :)

Comment: @ChrisW., any time.